# How to fix this Build Path Error?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, buildpath

This problem may the end of me. I have a red "!" over my project. I have learned this is a build path error. This is what comes up in the problems log.

```
 missing required Java project: 'appcompat_v7'          
 missing required Java project: 'appcompat_v7_2'    
 is missing required library: '\Copy of appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
 is missing required Java project: 'appcompat_v7_3' 
 is missing required library: '\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar'
```

I have tried cleaning, restoring, quickfix--> adding libraries, ect please help.

Comment: Please check Build target of your project. You can check it from Properties->Android. There should be latest target api selected if not then select latest one and then clean your application project.

Comment: It is currently on Android 4.4.2 - I have a minimum SDK of 16 and a Maximum SDK of 19 declared in my Android Manifest - if that is relevant.

Comment: It is because you have latest version of android i. e. kitkat. & when you create new project in android, it generates two things one is your app folder & another is appcompat. I guess you are closing or deleting that appcompat because of it you are getting this error. Another thing is follow User22791 steps.

Comment: U need to add the android-support-v4 from your library referencing in the main project lib folder

Comment: Right click on your app. Go to Properties -> Android -> Library. Check which library is added there. If you have already closed required appcompat library then it will show red cross mark so you just need to open that lib. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Android support v4.jar \appcompat_v7\libs is red (missing) 
same thing with v7\appcompat.jar\path\libs 
then I have android dependencies, private libs, and google api's. In my project it shows I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder.

Comment: Check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204659/eclipse-adt-appcompat-what-is-it

Answer (score 0):

> Go to your project properties and remove appcompat library. Also since
>   you have minSDK of 16 you dont need appcompat.