# Getting errors on eclipse because of appcompat_v7 (I think), missing R file in every project. How to fix this?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

My eclipse started showing these errors, two days back, have tried everything, still stuck. I have created a test project just to give some info about the errors I'm getting. Here's the console below:

```
    [2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] 
[2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] 
[2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-01-18 21:17:52 - test] 
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test] 
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test] 
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test] D:\New folder (2)\test\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-01-18 21:22:31 - test]
```

Tell me if you need something else. But please help me, I've tried all the solutions given to different questions here, so please do help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204659/eclipse-adt-appcompat-what-is-it

Comment: @MoubeenFarooqWarar Thank you for the comment, but can't you just wait until I try the answer given the link you gave? Let me do that and check if that answer fixes my problem or not, if it does then you can downvote the question.

Comment: I followed the instructions, given in the link. It solved the appcompat errors but my R file is still missing.@MoubeenFarooqWarar

Comment: have you installed Andtoid support library check it

Comment: @MoubeenFarooqWarar You there?

Comment: Yes it is there. I have installed it.

Comment: So, now what should I do?

Comment: download https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat and import it and donot forget to check copy projects in to workspace

Comment: after importing go to properties ->Android->add that library and then clean the projext and see

Comment: Done it, but didn't help. Still same errors, even in appcomat file.

Comment: Anymore ideas? If not, then atleast remove the downvote from the question!

Comment: i havent downvoted your question