# How to fix errors when adding support library v7 appcompat in eclipse in ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to develop the most simple "Hello World" application for android using [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm). However, after creating a "Hello World" project in eclipse (ubuntu 14.04), I get some errors regarding some "v7 appcompat" library which get me to [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204659/eclipse-adt-appcompat-what-is-it). Trying to 'Adding libraries with resources' as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), I followed the instructions, but after step 4 again multiple errors occur like

```
"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'."
```

How to fix those errors now? Is there a SIMPLE way to start a "Hello World" project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523026/cannot-add-android-support-v7-to-my-project-build-path follow this

Comment: Please, use Android Studio for a better experience in android development.

Comment: Also tried to install android studio as described here https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/132-mobile/779326-mobile-development-how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-version-1404 but no studio is being installed...